# Conditionally change pixel values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to create an image which two kernels and then a conditional was applied to pixels such as:

```
IF P1>0 AND P2>0 AND P1 + P2 > 100 THEN 1
IF NOT 0
```

I want a new image with pixels values are only 0 or 1 after the condition is applied.

Here is my progress:

```
var sentinelCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"),
    tRegion = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[28.182826834874845, 40.23986986920176],
          [28.147121268468595, 40.12970921265055],
          [28.227458792882658, 40.04355461665369],
          [28.421092826085783, 40.050913533775855],
          [28.525462943273283, 40.13075920541663],
          [28.462291556554533, 40.18953290914673],
          [28.415599662023283, 40.246159359987665]]]);

Map.centerObject(tRegion);

//Select images
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection(sentinelCollection
  .filterBounds(tRegion)
  .filterDate('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28')
  .select(['B8','B11','B12'])
  .first();

// Create a list of weights for a 13x13 kernel. 45 degree1
var line1a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line2a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0];
var line3a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0];
var line4a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0];
var line5a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line6a1 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var centera1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line8a1 =  [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line9a1 =  [0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line10a1 = [0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line11a1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line12a1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line13a1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var matrix45_a1 = [line1a1,line2a1,line3a1,
                   line4a1,line5a1,line6a1,
                           centera1,
                   line8a1,line9a1,line10a1,
                   line11a1,line12a1,line13a1];

// Create a list of weights for a 13x13 kernel. 45 degree2
var line1a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line2a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line3a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
var line4a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0];
var line5a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0];
var line6a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0];
var centera2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line8a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line9a2 =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line10a2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line11a2 = [0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line12a2 = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var line13a2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var matrix45_a2 = [line1a2,line2a2,line3a2,
                   line4a2,line5a2,line6a2,
                           centera2,
                   line8a2,line9a2,line10a2,
                   line11a2,line12a2,line13a2];

var kernela1 = ee.Kernel.fixed(13, 13, matrix45_a1);
print(kernela1);
var kernela2 = ee.Kernel.fixed(13, 13, matrix45_a2);
print(kernela2);

var convolvedA1 = sentinel.convolve(kernela1);
var convolvedA2 = sentinel.convolve(kernela2);
```

I want to apply abovementioned condition as `P1 = convolvedA1, P2 = convolvedA2`

How can I apply a condition to create new image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it but in case someone needs it, I'm sharing it as follows:

```
var conditionA1 = convolvedA1.gt(0)
var conditionA2 = convolvedA2.gt(0)
var conditionA12 = convolvedA1.updateMask(conditionA1)
                              .add(convolvedA2
                                   .updateMask(conditionA2))
                                               .gt(100)
```

(1) I created two binary images `1 IF Pixel > 0, 0 IF Pixel <= 0`
(2) I masked values where `Pixel = 0`
(3) I added pixel values of two images. It creates a masked image where the pixels do not follow my first condition `P1>0 and P2>0` are eliminated. So, my condition was basically changed to:

```
P1 + P2 IF P1>0 AND P2>0
```

(4) I applied the last condition `IF P1 + P2 > 100, 1 IF NOT 0` with `gt()` method which returns 1 if pixels are greater than 100.

Any other approach is highly appreciated.